# Shouldn't the IIS send Keep-Alive header

Tags: iis, keep-alive

I've enabled "HTTP keep-alive" in IIS 7.5 settings.
But still, the IIS doesn't respond with `Connection: keep-alive` header (to both FF and Chrome)

As I noticed, Nginx responds with this header when I enable keep-alive on it.

Shouldn't the `Connection: keep-alive` header be sent by server in response to requests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In HTTP/1.1 persistent connections are the default:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8

In other words, IIS doesn't really need to (however Apache seems to always send it).

You could verify this with netstat or as I tend to do with tcpview (a small sysinternals tool which you can download from microsoft:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx)

Comment: Ahh, then the answer is: Connection: Keep-Alive is default for HTTP/1.1

Comment: See this question for additional details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819622/iis-7-5-force-keep-alive-header-in-response

Answer (score 0):

It appears that IIS doesn't send the `Connection: keep-alive`. Still it doesn't close the connection and browser reuses it for further requests.