# IIS 7.5: Force Keep Alive header in Response

Tags: .net, iis, keep-alive

Based on my research, IIS 7.5 doesn't include the **Connection:Keep-Alive** in its response for reasons described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637473/shouldnt-the-iis-send-keep-alive-header). Unfortunately, I have a non conforming client connecting to my web service that won't reuse sockets unless it sees **Connection:Keep-Alive** in the response header.  I've tried programmatically adding this header but IIS appears to purposely strip it out. Is there any other way that I can force this header to be sent back to my naughty client?

Comment: Did you see this? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772183(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I re-installed IIS 7.5 on one of my servers and it appears to be a default setting there.

Comment: Mike, this setting doesn't appear to have any effect on the response.

Comment: I'll check my IIS at work when I can and sniff a request to see what I get.

Comment: Issue still exist in IIS 10 (in 2020). response doesn't have any effect whatever u set for "allowKeepAlive"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I opened a support ticket with Microsoft on this and had my worst suspicions confirmed.  IIS 7.5 deliberately prevents the connection:keep-alive header from being returned in the response. Per the HTTP 1.1 RFC, all connections should assume keep alive (a departure from HTTP 1.0).  Therefore, the omission of this header is the default and correct (?) behavior.  When keep-alives are **not** desirable, IIS will send the connection:close header.

What really surprised me is the great lengths to which IIS will go to to prevent this header from being sent.  Something within the IIS pipeline strips out this header no matter how it is added.  (C# code in my MVC application, IIS Manager-->HTTP Response Headers,IIS Manager-->URL Rewrite Module).

You would think MS would allow some sort of escape valve on this, given that there are so many non-conforming HTTP 1.1 clients in the wild that simply will not behave unless they see this header.

Comment: I had a similar problem with a legacy client recently, and looks like this issue still exists within IIS 8.5;  no way to force that header into the response.